# consulta con respecto a group BY con la funcion SUM

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

buenas tardes quiero crear una query que me permita sumar el total de productos que hay en un pedido tomando en cuenta que cada pedido puede estar repetido en una columna porque tiene diferentes productos asociados :

```
 select distinct  order_id as identificador_prueba,
       sum(items_quantity) suma_por_pedido
       from fulfillment.vw_shipedge_orders_items
       group by order_id
```

con esta quuery si logre lo que queria pero al tratar de traer otros campos de la misma tabla se distorsiona el valor de sum , porque tengo que declarar las otras columnas en group by
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la parte amarilla son los productos que contiene cada pedido e items_quantity son la cantidad individual que tiene cada producto dentro del pedido

yo quiero la suma del total de cada pedido ( sumando la cantidad de cada producto en el pedido )

como hago la query para que me traiga todos las columnas y asu vez repita el total del valor suma por cada pedido porque al ejecutar la query completa con todos los campos me distorsiona los valores

```
  select distinct items_sold_price,
                  items_sku ,
                  order_number,
                  order_id as identificador_prueba, 
       sum(distinct items_quantity) suma_por_pedido
       from fulfillment.vw_shipedge_orders_items
       group by order_id, order_number,items_sold_price,items_sku
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

( utilizo el distinct porque la tabla tiene errores no esta  normalizada y no puedo modificarla )
adicionalmente tengo que usar esa misma query y usar inner join con otras tablas

por ejemplo tabla 2 se llama : fulfillment.vw_shipedge_orders_items
solo para validar como quedaria la sintaxis con esta tabla , aunque si me es posible hacer un join con la misma tabla a si misma tambien me seria util ( he leido que es posible )

por favor si pudiesen ayudarme soy nuevo y apenas estoy aprendiendo de sql y big query
muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Tu primer consulta es la que te trae el total, el tema es que luego "desagrupas" al pedir también los datos de los producto del pedido. ¿Qué motor de base de datos usas?

Comment: si te refieres al SGBD que uso se llama DBeaver

Comment: No, se refiere a si es SQL Server, MySQL, Mongo... Los SGBD solo te permiten tener las Bases en GUI.

Comment: es SQLSERVER y utilizo el software dbeaver

Comment: @OCHOA Lo que mencionaste son justamente SGBD. _DBeaver_, _PHPMyAdmin_ y demás son nada más que herramientas gráficas, no son SGBD.

Comment: @padaleiana cierto, confundí el ultimo termino y puse el mismo :-S

Answer (score 0):

El distinct interior, está rompiendo la lógica de la suma de las cantidades.

```
create table vw_shipedge_orders_items
(
items_sold_price decimal(5,3),
items_sku varchar(100),
order_number int,
order_id varchar(100),
items_quantity int
)
Insert into  vw_shipedge_orders_items
(items_sold_price, items_sku, order_number, order_id, items_quantity)
values
(18.990, '8809326333661',14157,'100182.0',1),
(24.990, '8809486680407',14157,'100182.0',1),
(24.990, '8809486680407',14157,'100182.0',1),
(18.990, '8809326333661',14157,'100182.0',1),
(18.990, '8809416471655',14157,'100182.0',1),
(18.990, '8809416471655',14157,'100182.0',1);
```

Para el ejemplo, la parte de la imagen que has expuesto pero con los tipos de datos, que a mi me han parecido.

```
select
     distinct items_sold_price,
              items_sku ,
              order_number,
              order_id as identificador_prueba, 
              sum(items_quantity) suma_por_pedido
       from vw_shipedge_orders_items
       group by order_id, order_number,items_sold_price,items_sku;
```

[image: Res1]

Suma la cantidad, para cada item del pedido.

Para lo del join, abre un nuevo hilo y expon un escenario mejor.

[Group by](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/group-by-quizas-la-clausula-mas-conflictiva/)